# Badge for marking questions as favorite

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, badges, bookmarks

Has SO ever thought of implementing a badge for marking questions as favorite? I do not see a lot of this going on, and the badge count I believe reveals that. There are only around 2500 Favorite Question badges and 300 Stellar Question badges awarded.

Comment: brb, marking 100 questions favorite.

Comment: Obviously, with two down votes, the topic is a touchy subject, but is it really a bad question?

Comment: Votes on Meta don't mean the same thing as on the main sites.  It just means that people disagree with the feature request and don't want to see it implemented, not that it's *wrong* necessarily.

Comment: Yes, please don't freak out like we have had *several people do* this week.

Comment: Yes, it really is such a bad question

Comment: You moderators are an interesting bunch! Thanks @Bill.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is this a behavior that we really care to encourage?  Favorites are just there for our convenience.  Starring stuff just to give badges to other people for receiving our stars doesn't seem that useful.  (Compare that to badges that encourage both ends of voting, which is the most direct measure of quality on the sites.  Encouraging more voting is highly desirable.)

Answer (score 9):

This could easily be gamed. There are no limits on marking things as favorite, so you could just favorite anything and everything and get the badge immediately.

And what benefit is there to the community? You would get a flood of (potentially meaningless) favoriting, which would in turn give out many badges to the users who posted the questions, but how does this *help*? Badges that urge people to vote more could also be gamed to some degree, but with more voting going on we can better identify which answers are better than others, which questions are crap, etc. In other words, there is some benefit overall to the community by promoting that activity. I just don't see how badges for "favoriting X things" helps anyone.

To look at it another way, favoriting is really just a way to keep track of things you find helpful, interesting, notable, etc., so that you can navigate back to them later from your profile. It's more something you do for *your own benefit*, not for *the benefit of others*, so why is a reward needed?

Comment: and I *would*...

Comment: OK, so add a limit. It is the same principal as votes. You could just mark your 40 a day on random questions until you get the badges.

Comment: @Dustin Except the reason there's no limit is because it's a useful feature that has no benefit to abuse or really impact on anyone else's experience with the site.  Everything else that has a limit definitely impacts others' experiences.  To add a limit to something useful just to prevent gaming for a badge seems a little silly (yet without it the badge would be easily-gameable, so overall I dislike the suggestion)